# Asynchronous request boundary

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, networking

I am running a c# console app that does lots of async web request, and the best it does is 100 request in a minute, no matter how many request I send.

But when I run this app on two different machines on the same LAN, they both run at the same speed of 100 request per minute, which makes me think that there is some sort of limitation at windows level.

Anyone knows anything about this and about removing it?

Some code as requested:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

for (int Index = 0; Index < 30000; Index++)
{
   if (Index % 100 == 0 && Index != 0)
   {
      Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
      tasks.Clear();
   }

   tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Request(Index); }));
}

private void Request(int Index)
{
    g_List.Add(WebClient.DownloadString("http://www.exmaple.com?s=" + Index));
}
```

Comment: Are you parallelizing these requests?  Could just be the ping times to the server.

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: i am using c# Tasks for parallelization, i also tried plain async request but it stayed the same, i edited the question with some code

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? Also, is `g_List` thread safe in it's `Add` method (if it is a `List<string>` the answer is "No")

Comment: i am using .NET 4.5, g_list is not thread safe i am actually using lock(g_list) on the addition, i didn't think it matter